# How to get ng-template and ngModel in component using contentChild

Tags: angular

My requirement is to get `ngModel` as well as `ng-template`

This is how I get access to `ng-template`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sample',
  template: `<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="container"></ng-template>`
})
@ContentChild('container') container: TemplateRef<any>;
```

The above code gives access to `ng-template` I am able to display that in `ngTemplateOutlet`.

However I am not able to get access to `ngModel`

This is what I have tried

```
@ContentChild(NgModel) model: NgModel; //undefined
this.container.elementRef.nativeElement // <!--container-->
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fpb2zv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forked your Stackblitz Example and changed few lines:

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tmrqpx)

```
@ContentChild(NgModel) model: NgModel;
```

into

```
@ContentChildren(NgModel) model: QueryList<NgModel>;
```

And subscribe to changes of the 'model' Variable:

```
this.model.changes.pipe(first()).subscribe(res => {
    const ctrl = res.first as NgModel;
    console.log("ctrl", ctrl);
});
```

Comment: Thanks that works for `ngModel`, How do I get reference to `HTMLInputElement` ?

Comment: @SameerKhan i've updated my fork of your Stackblitz Example.
But i'm quite not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am displaying `ng-template` dynamically and when input element is found then focusing on it and validating with `ngModel`